# make a decision without if statement

Tags: if-statement

I want to convert this code to another code without switch or if statement.

Any help, please?

It's a job interview question

```
if(x==9)
return "3";
if (x==3)
return "9";
else
return "not valid";
```

where x is a user input

Comment: A job interview question?  Perhaps more research should be carried out, rather than  asking for the answer.

Comment: @S3DEV if it's that easy you can help .And searching with me for the answer could make help because I can't find answer for this question that why I'm asking!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a ternary?

```
    String result = x == 9 ? "3" : "not valid";
    result = x == 3 ? "9" : result;
    return result;
```

Or a map with a ternary?

```
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(9, "3");
    map.put(3, "9");
    String result = map.get(x);
    return result == null ? "not valid" : result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary?

```cs
private static readonly Values = new Dictionary {{ 3 => "9", 9 => "3" }};

// Usage
var value = 10; // user input
return values.GetValueOrDeafult(value, "not valid");
```